# SignalR cross-domain without CORS

Tags: asp.net, cross-domain, signalr, cors

I'm trying to get a confirmation that yes, a client can send and receive messages to an ASP.NET site on another domain without requiring that the IIS server running the SignalR-enabled ASP.NET supports CORS.

Can someone provide me with an example I can look at where CORS *is not* used as the cross-domain mechanism?

*We have IE 9 clients and want to have three sites on different domains push/pull to a single ASP.NET + SignalR server. Can this be done? How?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cors is not available SignalR uses longPolling transport with jsonp.

Keep in mind jsonp is insecure by design AND can limit your data you send over the wire since all data is sent via the query string.

You should not have to provide any additional information on the client for SignalR to use jsonp, it should just work.

To ensure that cross domain communication works on the server you'll have to enable it:

```
Routes.RouteTable.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable this when using SignalR 2.0 with the OWIN middleware instead of the regular ASP.NET pipeline, install the `Microsoft.Owin.Cors` package from NuGet, then do something like this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(OwinStartup))]

namespace Website.App_Start
{
    public partial class OwinStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                map.RunSignalR(new HubConfiguration {EnableJSONP = true});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More details here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, WebSockets (cross origin) will require CORS, so eventually (if you want to use web sockets) you will need to support this on the server.